# Querying Microsoft devops azure commits to display on an "update" page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-devops

I'm reworking our companies management website and would like to display any commits or updates on our devops azure page on an "update" page for admins to view.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check out Azure devops Rest api to retrieve the git commits for a project.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.1`

You probably need write codes to extract and display the required properties(eg. commiter, author, url, etc.) of 
 commits from the results.

You can check the examples in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#assemble-the-request) to learn how to make azure devops service rest api calls.

You can also check out the [.NET client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet). For git Commits you can refer to [GitHttpClientBase.GetCommitsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getcommitsasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet) Method.

Hope above helps!

Comment: Oh ok, That is a shame. I already know all about the pull requests, policies and so on. We already have that setup. I just wanted a nice styled page on our actual website for laymen people to view. Like our sales rep for an example.

Comment: Sorry I think i misunderstood you. I thought you want to query the commits and display on an azure devops page. You can get all the commits with [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). Check above update.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you yes this is what I meant. Thanks for the update